# When updating cloudformation stack validationissue is coming

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When trying to update cloudformation stack below issue is coming. I found this error in cloudtrail logs.

"errorCode": "ValidationException",
"errorMessage": "No updates are to be performed."

what could be the reason ? i am trying to update parameters in CFT stck

Comment: Can you provide example template, describe exactly what you are changing and how?

Comment: I do not have access to CFT Template. I have provisioned service catalog product which has created CloudFormation stack. now i want to update some parameters value in cloudformation stack so i am updating provisioned service catalog which should update cloudformation stack but provisioned service catalog is getting updated but it is not updating cloudformation stack so i tried to figure out issue with cloud trail and i found  errorCode": "ValidationException", "errorMessage": "No updates are to be performed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, there were some set of parameters which needs to be updated for auto scaling. it was not allowing to update single parameters.

by modifying some other parameters it started working